# "Most" irreducible representations of "most" finite groups are one-dimensional

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory

Looking through the character tables of the [groups](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/index120.html) on this list, it seems like most irreducible representations of most groups on the list will be one-dimensional.

I'm looking for a reference request: is there a result formalizing this observation?

Comment: It is "known" that if you include exactly one finite group of each isomorphism type into a list, sorted by order, then most groups on that list have order that is a power of two. If $G$ is one of them, then the index of the commutator subgroup calculates the number of non-isomorphic 1-dimensional representations of $G$. Alas, I have no idea about the relative frequencies of that index within the class of $2$-groups.

Comment: The large class of groups of order $2^n$ defined by Graham Higman have nilpotency class 2 with $G/G'$ of order about $2^{2n/3}$. If such examples dominate the finite groups, then the answer to the question is yes. But that answer depends on the truth of conjectures which noone has any idea how to prove.